# Add text and attribute to div depending on url with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On page load, I'm trying to add the text (capitalized) of the last part of the url to a `li` and its attribute `data-filter` (with a dot behind).

For example, if the page has this url:

`www.myexample.com/#commisions`

the `li` would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a data-filter=".commisions" href="#">Commisions</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried with this method but it doesn't remove the `#` from the text:

```
var url = document.URL
var cuturl = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$( ".navbar-brand" ).html( cuturl );
```

Any idea how can achieve it?

Comment: Use [location hash property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

Comment: `location.hash.substr(1)` or `url.split('#')[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = document.URL;
var cuturl = url.split("#")[1];
$("li a").html(cuturl);
$("li a").attr('data-filter','.'+cuturl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `"\"` with `"#"`

```
var cuturl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
```

or

```
var cuturl = url.split("#")[1];
```